# Should I use the different Ad Unit ID for BANNER and SMART BANNER in my android app

Tags: android

In my android app ad unit ID is working as SMART BANNER but not working as BANNER.
Do i have to create different ad units for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3

As per the Documentation you are getting the following error code:

public static final int ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL

The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.

Constant Value: 3

Based on the post onFailedToReceiveAd - Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory when using admob with adwhirl:

If you are getting this error, then your code is correct. The issue is that AdMob does not always have an ad to return for every request. This may happen particularly if you have just registered your AdMob publisher ID, as it takes some time and multiple requests before the new ID starts returning ads.

Another reason your fill rate may be low is that you don't have AdSense backfill enabled, or you have filtered out some ads. Check your app settings to see if that is the case.

Comment: same ad unit working as BANNER and SMART BANNER but as BANNER it is not loading every time.

Comment: Do you getting any error response while fetching ad?

Comment: No problems. It's always a pleasure. You can mark it as accepted or helpful so other can get benefit.